# How to get a list of Row Policies in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

the PostgreSQL-Documentation describes how to create or drop a row policy, *but not* how to get a list of the existing ones.
My aim is to be able to know, by using pgAdmin, if there are row policies affecting a table and how they work.

Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer :  everything is in the pg_catalog.pg_policies view.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

More helpful than catalog view [pg_policy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-policy.html) is [pg_policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/view-pg-policies.html). You see what table it applies to and even what the policy does (though that seems to get truncated).

So just run: `select * from pg_policies`

which actually boils down to this (thanks to @jmelesky):

```
 SELECT n.nspname AS schemaname,
    c.relname AS tablename,
    pol.polname AS policyname,
        CASE
            WHEN pol.polpermissive THEN 'PERMISSIVE'::text
            ELSE 'RESTRICTIVE'::text
        END AS permissive,
        CASE
            WHEN pol.polroles = '{0}'::oid[] THEN string_to_array('public'::text, ''::text)::name[]
            ELSE ARRAY( SELECT pg_authid.rolname
               FROM pg_authid
              WHERE pg_authid.oid = ANY (pol.polroles)
              ORDER BY pg_authid.rolname)
        END AS roles,
        CASE pol.polcmd
            WHEN 'r'::"char" THEN 'SELECT'::text
            WHEN 'a'::"char" THEN 'INSERT'::text
            WHEN 'w'::"char" THEN 'UPDATE'::text
            WHEN 'd'::"char" THEN 'DELETE'::text
            WHEN '*'::"char" THEN 'ALL'::text
            ELSE NULL::text
        END AS cmd,
    pg_get_expr(pol.polqual, pol.polrelid) AS qual,
    pg_get_expr(pol.polwithcheck, pol.polrelid) AS with_check
   FROM pg_policy pol
     JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = pol.polrelid
     LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a catalog view that holds what you want: [`pg_policy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-policy.html). It's a little obscure, but it holds what you need.

```
# \d pg_policy
      Table "pg_catalog.pg_policy"
    Column    |     Type     | Modifiers 
--------------+--------------+-----------
 polname      | name         | not null
 polrelid     | oid          | not null
 polcmd       | "char"       | not null
 polroles     | oid[]        | 
 polqual      | pg_node_tree | 
 polwithcheck | pg_node_tree | 
Indexes:
    "pg_policy_oid_index" UNIQUE, btree (oid)
    "pg_policy_polrelid_polname_index" UNIQUE, btree (polrelid, polname)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, you can't see what the policy really does

Comment: Ho, my bad. I looked in the pg_policy table instead of the pg_policies view. It's got all I needed !

Comment: Obscure is correct. Does anyone now how to get table names, probably via `polrelid`?

Comment: @Alex, the `pg_policies` view has `schemaname` and `tablename`, which you can get by querying `pg_class` with the `polrelid`, and then `pg_namespace` from the `class.relnamespace`. That sounds tedious, but you can also do a `\d+ pg_policies` to get the view query, which you can then edit to get the info however you need.

Answer (score -1):

Since version `4.23` - pgAdmin supports RLS Policies.

- https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/release_notes_4_23.html